# How to hide an accordion on page load and show only on click on an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have following code to show an accordion  in Fancybox popup.But  on page load I do not want to show the accordion.If I hide it the content is also hidden on showing the accordion in popup.

On clicking on *Click For The Instructions* I want to show the accordion.I wnat to keep the fancybox functionality also.

My code is as following

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

  });
  jQuery("#homepage_popup_welcome").fancybox().trigger('click'); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<a id = "homepage_popup_welcome" href="#mydiv" style="">Click For The Instructions</a>


    <div id = "mydiv" style = "width:900px;display:none;">   <!-- See the display none -->
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>Section 1</h3>
              <div>
                <p>
                Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
                ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
                amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
                odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
                </p>
              </div>
              <h3>Section 2</h3>
              <div>
                <p>
                Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
                purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
                velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
                suscipit faucibus urna.
                </p>
              </div>
              <h3>Section 3</h3>
              <div>
                <p>
                Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
                Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
                ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
                lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
                </p>
                <ul>
                  <li>List item one</li>
                  <li>List item two</li>
                  <li>List item three</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <h3>Section 4</h3>
              <div>
                <p>
                Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
                et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
                faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
                mauris vel est.
                </p>
                <p>
                Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
                Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
                inceptos himenaeos.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

If I remove  `display:none`  from `<div id = "mydiv" style = "width:900px;display:none;">` the accordion is visible on page load also.

On page load the link should only be visible not the accordion.

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not put `display:none` in inline style. Do it through your css, put it on `#mydiv` and then have it revealed with onclick function

```
#accordion{
display:none;
}
```

You can also add it to your `<head>` section if you are not using style-sheet.

Comment: put display:none on #accordion